# How to do pagination in list method with multiple sorted serializers django rest framework views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-itertools, django-serializer

I am trying to combine two serializers(Post and PostShare) in in one single view to show in my feeds. Here is my View

```
class PostAPIView(
mixins.CreateModelMixin, 
generics.ListAPIView,
ObjectMultipleModelAPIView,
mixins.ListModelMixin,
ListView): 
    permission_classes          = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class            = PostSerializer
    # filter_backends             = [filters.OrderingFilter,filters.SearchFilter, 
django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
    # filter_fields               = ['author']
    # search_fields               = ['content','author']
    # ordering_fields             = ['created_at']
    # ordering                    = ['-created_at']
    pagination_class            = LimitOffsetPagination

    # pagination_class = LimitPagination
    default_limit = 2
    # # paginate_by = 2
    # # page_size=2
    # #queryset = Post.objects.all()
    def list(self, request, format = None, **kwargs):

        posts = Post.objects.all()
        post_shares = PostShare.objects.all() 

        serializer_post = PostSerializer(posts,many=True).data
        serializer_post_share = PostShareReadSerializer(post_shares,many=True).data
        # rr=sorted(list(chain(posts,post_shares)), key=lambda x: x.created_at,reverse = 
         True)


        # print(rr)
        result_lst = sorted(serializer_post + serializer_post_share, key=lambda x: x.get('created_at'),reverse = True)
        print(result_lst)
        # page = self.paginate_queryset(result_lst,2)
        # paginator_request_var = "page"
        # page = request.GET.get(paginator_request_var)
        # posts = paginator.get_page(page)

        # return Response(result_lst_page,context)
        # print(result_lst)
        # return self.get_paginated_response(result_lst)
        return Response(result_lst)
```

This is not working in get_queryset so I put it in list method but this is not showing me pagination. Is there any way I can paginate my result? or any other approach to combine these querysets and serializers with pagination?

**EDIT 1**
I tried ObjectMultipleModelAPIView and put `querylist = [
        {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostSerializer},
        {'queryset': PostShare.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostShareReadSerializer},
        ....
    ]`
in my queryset method and outside it but got error

> "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `medias` on serializer `PostSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'medias'."
>   Here's my PostSerializer
>   class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = [
        ....
        'medias',
        ....
    ]
   def create(self, validated_data):
    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
        user = request.user
    media_data = validated_data.pop('medias')

    post = Post.objects.create(author= user, **validated_data)
    for media in media_data:
        media = Media.objects.create(author= user, **media)
        post.medias.add(media)


    post.save()
    return post
```

What am I missing here? Can't I simply paginate my list method because I am getting the output in the format I want

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `drf_multiple_model` - https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels

It does what you want in a cleaner way.

```
from drf_multiple_model.views import ObjectMultipleModelAPIView

class PostAPIView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [
        {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostSerializer},
        {'queryset': PostShare.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostShareReadSerializer},
        ....
    ]
```

Comment: I tried to put this in get_queryset method but got an error ""Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `medias` on serializer `PostSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'medias'.""